# import wildcard ssl in tomcat - getting NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: tomcat, ssl, openssl

I have received a pkcs#7 format certificate from SSL2Buy. I have followed following steps to import the certificate in keystore:

1. Generate private key using :
   **openssl genrsa -aes256 -out 'appServer.key' 2048**
2. Generate a certificate signing request 
   **openssl req -new -key appServer.key -out appServer.csr**

Here CN I have tried the wild card domain - *.mydomain.com
3. Get it CA signed with the key & certificate received

**openssl x509 -req -in appServer.csr -CA certificate.pem -CAkey rsa.key -CAcreateserial -out appServert.crt -days 365 -sha256**

4. Combine  appServer.key & appServert.crt into one file appserver.pem
   **cat appServer.key  appServert.crt > appserver.pem**
5. convert it into keystore understandable format

**openssl pkcs12 -export -out appserver.pkcs12 -in appserver.pem**

6. Import this pkcs12 file into our App server’s keystore file 
   **$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore appserver.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore -deststoretype JKS**
7. Change alias

**$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -changealias -keystore keystore -alias 1 -destalias tomcat**

8. Convert the pkcs#7 format file to pem and then import is the certificate.pem certificate into this keystore

**openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in stats.p7b -out certificate.pem**

**$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -keystore keystore -import -file certificate.pem -alias tomcat1**

Now in tomcat's server.xml, I have used the above keystore file and restarted the server. When I load the url https://abc.mydomain.com:9443 I am getting NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error

Comment: Do you have `Advanced` link before the `Back to Safety` button?

Comment: @hiren Yes I can see the Advanced Link

Comment: Just press that link and click Proceed. It will ask the first time. Moving forward it will directly proceed.

Comment: @hiren - If I do that then in the url - top left corner its stating not secure

Comment: That probably means that the certificate is Invalid,

Comment: @hiren - but the certificate is valid, if I open the page in mozilla it works.. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try adding your certificate in `Chrome` from Settings-> Manage Certificates. Import your certificate here. Ctrl-F5. See what happens.